# Accessing first element of a matrix in Isabelle

Tags: matrix, isabelle

Accessing the “first” element of a matrix

I want to write a proof about a trivial case of the determinant of a matrix, where the matrix consists of just a single element (i.e., the cardinality of `'n` is one).

Thus the determinant (or `det A`) is the single element in the matrix.

However, it is not clear to me how to reference the single element of the matrix. I tried `A $ zero $ zero`, which did not work.

My current way to demonstrate the problem is to write `∀a∈(UNIV :: 'n set). det A = A $ a $ a`. It assumes that the cardinality of the numeral type is one.

What is the correct way to write this trivial proof about determinants?

Here is my current code:

```
theory Notepad
imports
  Main
  "~~/src/HOL/Library/Polynomial"
  "~~/src/HOL/Algebra/Ring"
  "~~/src/HOL/Library/Numeral_Type"
  "~~/src/HOL/Library/Permutations"
  "~~/src/HOL/Multivariate_Analysis/Determinants"
  "~~/src/HOL/Multivariate_Analysis/L2_Norm"
  "~~/src/HOL/Library/Numeral_Type"
begin


lemma det_one_element_matrix:
fixes A :: "('a::comm_ring_1)^'n∷finite^'n∷finite"
assumes "card(UNIV :: 'n set) = 1"
shows "∀a∈(UNIV :: 'n set). det A = A $ a $ a"
proof-

  (*sledgehammer proof of 1, 2 and ?thesis *)
  have 1: "∀a∈(UNIV :: 'n set). UNIV = {a}"   
  by (metis (full_types) Set.set_insert UNIV_I assms card_1_exists ex_in_conv)

  have 2:
  "det A = (∏i∈UNIV. A $ i $ i)" 
  by (metis (mono_tags, lifting) "1" UNIV_I det_diagonal singletonD)

  from 1 2 show ?thesis by (metis setprod_singleton)

qed
```

---

***UPDATE:***

Unfortunately, this is part of a larger theorem which is already proven for the cardinality of `'n∷finite` > 1. In this theorem the type of matrix A is 
fixed as `A :: "('a::comm_ring_1)^'n∷finite^'n∷finite` and the definition of the determinant is used in this larger theorem.

Therefore, I don't think I can change the type of my matrix A to `('a::comm_ring_1)^1^1)` in oder to solve my larger theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that my previous answer is the better solution in general if it is possible to use, so I will leave it as-is. In your case where you are not able to use this approach, things get a little harder, unfortunately.

What you need to show is that:

- There can only be a single element in your type `'n`, and thus every element is equal;
- Additionally, the definition of `det` also references permutations, so we need to show that there only exists a single function of type `'n ⇒ 'n`, which happens to be equal to the function `id`.

With these in place, we can carry out the proof as follows:

```
lemma det_one_element_matrix:
  fixes A :: "('a::comm_ring_1)^'n∷finite^'n∷finite"
  assumes "card(UNIV :: 'n set) = 1"
  shows "det A = A $ x $ x"
proof-
  have 0: "⋀x y. (x :: 'n) = y"
    by (metis (full_types) UNIV_I assms card_1_exists)

  hence 1: "(UNIV :: 'n set) = {x}"
    by auto

  have 2: "(UNIV :: ('n ⇒ 'n) set) = {id}"
    by (auto intro!: ext simp: 0)

  thus ?thesis
    by (auto simp: det_def permutes_def 0 1 2 sign_id)
qed
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `A $ zero $ zero` (or `A $ 0 $ 0`) wouldn't have worked, because the vectors are indexed from 1: `A $ 0 $ 0` is undefined, which makes it hard to prove anything about.

Playing a little myself, I came up with the following lemma:

```
lemma det_one_element_matrix:
   "det (A :: ('a::comm_ring_1)^1^1) = A $ 1 $ 1"
  by (clarsimp simp: det_def sign_def)
```

Instead of using a type `'a :: finite` and assuming it has cardinality 1, I used the standard Isabelle `1` type which encodes both these facts into the type itself. (Similar types exist for all numerals, so you can write things like `'a ^ 23 ^ 72`)

Incidentally, after typing in the lemma above, `auto solve_direct` quickly informed me that something already exists in the library stating the same result, a lemma named `det_1`.

Comment: I added the following update to my question: Unfortunately, this is part of a larger theorem which is already proven for the cardinality of 'n∷finite > 1. In this theorem the type of matrix A is fixed as A :: "('a::comm_ring_1)^'n∷finite^'n∷finite and the definition of the determinant is used in this larger theorem.

Therefore I don't think I can change type of my matrix A to ('a::comm_ring_1)^1^1) in oder to solve my larger theorem.